# Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'

Tags: haskell

I am working on Project Euler #41, and this is part of my solution to the problem which I can't figure out how to get around Haskell expecting an `[Int]` instead of an `[Integer]`. Diglist works fine but I included it just in case the error somehow involves it.

```
digList :: Integer -> [Integer]
digList n = digList' [] n where
        digList' xs n
                | n < 10        = n : xs
                | otherwise = digList' (lsd : xs) nxt
                where
                    lsd = n `mod` 10
                    nxt = n `div` 10

isNPandigital :: Integer -> Bool
isNPandigital n = isnp 1 (digList n) where --error on this line
    isnp i xs
        | i `elem` xs = isnp i $ delete i xs
        | i == length (digList n) = null xs
        | otherwise = False
```

The error is:

```
Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'
Expected type: [Int]
Actual type: [Integer]
In the return type of a call of `digList'
In the second argument of `isnp', namely `(digList n)'
In the expression: isnp 1 (digList n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `i` to `isnp` is inferred to be `Int` because you use `` i `elem` xs ``, and because you use `i == length (digList n)`.  The compiler sees that `i` should be an `Int` since you're comparing it to `length (digList n)`, which always returns an `Int`, and you're using `` i `elem` xs ``, so `xs` must have the type `[Int]`, but you pass in `(digList n)` for `xs`, and `digList n` has type `[Integer]`, hence the error.

Comment: Interesting. What would the idiomatic way to handle this type difference in Haskell be? I ended up doing `(toInteger . length . digList) xs` so that ghc would infer `i`'s type to be `Integer` but the extra call to toInteger seems... dirty to me.

Comment: @wolf you can also use `genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i`. It's slightly slower than just `length` but can return any kind of number.